# How to react to the fail condition while testing with Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is my test for the login feature of my NodeJS application:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
   withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
   build();

driver.get('localhost:3012');
var loginForm = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('login'));
loginForm.findElement(webdriver.By.name('email')).sendKeys('abcd@abcd.com');
loginForm.findElement(webdriver.By.name('password')).sendKeys('1234s');
loginForm.submit();

driver.wait(function() {
    return driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('welcomeMsg')) !== null;
}, 1000);

driver.quit();
```

If the login is successful, everything is alright.

But if it fails, the test never stops.

How do I deal with this?

(Note: There is no documentation of the API for Selenium WebDriver with **JS** I could find. So I had to ask here.)

Comment: How is the login failing, exactly?

Comment: @Richard, the password is wrong. So it shouldn't move to a page with a `welcomeMsg` element.

Comment: When the login fails, what do you see in your browser? Do you get a sensible error page?

Comment: @Louis, yes I do. But I wanted the test to stop. The purpose of the test was to show that the app doesn't allow false username+password combos to work.

Comment: "But I wanted the test to stop." Yeah, I understand. I was asking because, for instance, if your browser had been hanging there with a spinning icon (still downloading), it could have been that your server never terminated its HTTP response: a server error. I can't see why your code just hangs, because using `driver.wait` should fail with an exception. Unfortunately, I don't know what nits the JS version of Selenium has because I used it for a very little bit, ran into bugs and then decided to switch to the Python bindings, which I was using anyway for other tests.